# Django Model related Field Clash

Tags: django-models, pinax

Consider the following model:

```
class FPModel(models.Model):
    # The user who created
    author = models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User, null=False)
    # The user who last edited
    editor = models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User, null=True)
    # Create Time
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # Modify Time
    edited_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I will be auto-populating the author and editor fields from django admin.

When I sync the database I am getting the following error:

```
(pinax-env)gautam@Aspirebuntu:$
 python manage.py syncdb
Error: One or more models did not validate:
FP.fpmodel: Accessor for field 'author' clashes with related field 'User.fpmodel_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'author'.
FP.fpmodel: Accessor for field 'editor' clashes with related field 'User.fpmodel_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'editor'.
```

I am using `django 1.2.5` and `pinax 0.7.2`.

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from the docs, specifically [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-related-name).

I have to use

```
author = models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User , null = False ,related_name="%(class)s_related_author" ) # The user who created 
editor = models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User , null = True,related_name="%(class)s_related_editor" ) # The user who last edited
```

Comment: both are 'page not found' links. Please give an updated link